# Disable the previous selected item to prevent duplicate rows using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I add dynamically multiple rows, I have a selected-box in my additional rows.

I have the following script and view, which dynamically adds multiple rows.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
  var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
  var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;

  //added data-index and outer..class
  $(".form_field_outer").append(
`<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
        <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
          <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
                  <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    @foreach($castings as $casting)
                    <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>  
          <div class="card-body">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
<div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
  <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
        <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          @foreach($castings as $casting)
            <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg top-right-button mr-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
      </div>
      <div class="casting_details">
        <div class="casting_details2">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want when I select an item from the first additional row this item should be disabled for all the next additional rows to prevent duplicate rows .

The goal is to disable all the selected item in the previous rows.

If you have any idea about how can I acheive that I would be grathfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - create a separate function to run every time there is a select item change. You'll need to make it a delegate listener since the selects are dynamically created, and that funciton will need to run every time a select menu is updated and/or when a new select menu is created.

I replaced your select options for testing

```js
$("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
  var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
  var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
  //added data-index and outer..class
  $(".form_field_outer").append(
    `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
            <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select  class="form-control maintCostField"  name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting" >
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2'>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>                
    </select>
</div>  
    <div class="card-body ">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
    </div>
    </div> </div></div> `);
  manageDisabled()

});

$(".form_field_outer").on("change", "select.maintCostField", function() {
  manageDisabled()
})

function manageDisabled() {
  let disabled = [];
  $('select.maintCostField option:selected').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('value')) disabled.push($(this).attr('value'))
  })

  $('select.maintCostField option').not(':selected').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', disabled.includes($(this).attr('value')));
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
      <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
        <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option value='1'>1</option>
              <option value='2'>2</option>
              <option value='3'>3</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg top-right-button mr-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
          </div>
          <div class="casting_details">
            <div class="casting_details2">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```